# JMeter, Divide URLs from CSV among users randomly (or equally) without a URL being called more than once

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation where I have 100000 URLs in CSV file and I would like to start N number of users (Threads) simultaneously but they should be taking part of CSV file without interfering with each other's data set.

```
Url1
Url2
....
Url100000
```

`User1` should take from `Url1-Url100` , `User2` should take from `Url101-Url200` and so on.. (not necessarily equal splits) but a URL should only be hot once. And All the users must start at the same time to achieve my desired load.

I can split files into multiple CSVs and create multiple thread groups but it's not practically possible to create 1000 thread groups if I have 1000 users.

Tried multiple approaches (`OnceOnlyController` and `ThroughputController`) but didn't help.

Any inputs on this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To make your users take unique lines from the CSV file just set [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) to `All Threads`

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config Sharing Mode]
2. Another way to make requests "unique" is switching to [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function, but in this case you will have to manually calculate the number of iterations (virtual users * loops should be <= the number of lines in the .csv file), otherwise there will be repeated URLs.
3. And finally there is [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) plugin which can guarantee uniqueness even for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
4. To start your threads at exactly the same moment either set Ramp Up in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to `0` or use [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)